# Is it possible to delete all rows for a specific column at once in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

This is not a question asking how to delete all data for a table.
That's what `TRUNCATE` does.

I want to delete all rows for a specific column at once in cassandra.
I can delete only one row for a specific column using `DELETE` or `UPDATE` like the follows.

```
DELETE column_name FROM table_name WHERE primary_key = value_of_primary_key;
```

or

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = null WHERE primary_key = value_of_primary_key;
```

However, what I want to do is like the follows.

```
TRUNCATE key_name.table_name.column_name;
```

The above `TRUNCATE` code doesn't work since it doesn't take `column_name`, but I hope you understand what I want to do.

Is it possible to delete all rows for a specific column at once?

If so, how can I do that?

If not, what is the best workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Drop the column and Add the column again.

Example :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP column_name;
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name text;
```